# Getting UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION while updating SharingCriteriaRule using Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, sharing-rule, unexpectedexception

I am trying to update the access of SharingRule using the Metadata API from APEX. I have created a MetadataService class using https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls. I also created a SharingRuleUpdater class with method to update the SharingRule.

```
public without sharing class SharingRuleUpdater {

  public void updateSharingRule(String sharingRuleName, String accessLevel) {
    // Create the metadata API client
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

    
    MetadataService.SharingCriteriaRule scr = new MetadataService.SharingCriteriaRule();
    scr.fullName = sharingRuleName;
    scr.accessLevel = accessLevel;
      
      // Update the sharing rule
    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> result = service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] {scr});
    System.debug('result-->'+result);
  }
}
```

After that I have created **Shift_Sharing_Rule** SharingCriteriaRule on **Shift__c** custom object. I am executing below code to update the access of this SharingRule

```
SharingRuleUpdater sru = new SharingRuleUpdater();
sru.updateSharingRule('Shift__c.Shift_Sharing_Rule','Edit');
```

Executing above code is giving below error

```
message=An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support:...., message_type_info=(message, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false), statusCode=UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION
```

Comment: Can you include the complete error message? Is there a [GACK ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tag/gack)?

Comment: Please find this error message `message=An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1488460070-151344 (985879857), message_type_info=(message, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false), statusCode=UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, statusCode_type_info=(statusCode, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false)]), errors_type_info=(errors, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, -1, false), field_order_type_info=(errors, fullName, success), fullName=Shift.Shift_Sharing_Rule,`

Comment: From Salesforce internal logs,I can see that the stacktrace  `985879857` corresponds to `java.lang.NullPointerException on id null`

Comment: Thanks Swetha. I will check regarding that. Also, will you be able to help for finding which id is missing?